# Including an XCode project product into another project

Tags: xcode, build, include, product

Within an XCode project I have createed a new ColorPicker (MyCustomPicker.colorPicker).
Then I have a second project, where I would like to use that colorPicker.

Once I build it, I can manually copy the colorPicker to the appropriate location within the app package and use it when I start the app.

How can I achieve the automatic transfer of the colorPicker to the correct folder at build time of the second project?

I need to automate this process and further, once I sign the app, the colorPicker should be already present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I dragged the whole colorPicker XCode project in the main one and then edited the following:

- in Build Phases I marked the dependency
- I removed the colorPicker files in "Compile sources" list
- I added a build phase "Copy files", selected "Resources", subpath "ColorPickers" and added colorPicker product